# OpenCV Fill Holes in Binary Mat for Multiple Objects

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have objects that appear as white halos in a binary threshold matrix. I made this code to fill the halos white so I can have solid white circles in the matrix:

```
void processBinary(Mat& binaryMat) {
  Mat clone;
  binaryMat.copyTo(clone);
  vector<vector<Point>> contours;
  findContours(clone, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

  if (!contours.empty()) {
      drawContours(binaryMat, contours, 0, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
  }
}
```

This works if I only have one object in the camera feed. However, with multiple of the same objects, it won't perform the filling on any object unless I remove all but one of the objects from the scene. How can I fix the code so that each object is filled to be a solid white circle?

Comment: try `drawContours(binaryMat, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);`

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Does the drawContours method loop through all contours ?
Controls are basically given as linked list tyhat has to be looped to get them all by calling while(contours!=null)
....
contours = contours.VNext;//Or HNext for depending on your code.